# CentOS 7: Slow wifi since some days ago

Tags: centos, wifi

I'm using CentOS 7 and some days ago I started having slow wifi. These are some of my outputs (less than 1Mbps):

`uname -a`

```
Linux lhost.ldomain 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 26 15:27:06 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`ifconfig`

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d4:81:d7:e8:0b:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xef200000-ef220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 691156  bytes 541358280 (516.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 691156  bytes 541358280 (516.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:5e:a3:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 2003:cf:732:1de0:b426:4f6f:c778:b5db  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::bb97:5650:6ef7:9493  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:4d:70:c0:fb:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1473038  bytes 943223376 (899.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 718634  bytes 181148123 (172.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`iwconfig wlp2s0`

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID: ***removed as suggested***
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: ***removed as suggested***
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:14  Invalid misc:534   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Please show the output of `iwconfig wlp2s0` You might want to remove your ESSID name and MAC address.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I added that output on the original post (here I can't make it appear correctly). I home I've removed all the things you suggested.

Comment: @ambrose this is the appropriate way to add information: you [edit] your question - well done :-))

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided output, your Wi-Fi adapter is running at 144.4 Mb/s with a very decent signal to noise ratio which could indicate

1. A temporary hardware malfunction (try rebooting your device)
2. Some sort of issue with your access point (try rebooting the AP)
3. A severe WiFi congestion (run any WiFi analyzer for your phone and check if you have any other access points sharing your radio frequency - change it if that's the case)
4. You are not using VPN, are you? If you are, try disconnecting/reconnecting to it.
5. Check your `dmesg` output for warnings/errors (they will be prepended with `iwlwifi`).
6. Try updating your kernel or/and WiFi firmware.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. There seems to be no warnings/errors prepended with iwlwifi. I have already rebooted, I'm not using VPN, and everything is updated. If I avoid using the wifi repeater I'm using it seems to work fine, but it's not the repeater, since it works fine with anoher wifi signal. I'm not sure how to do the radio frequency thing (I'm not on my phone) but with dmesg I got messages like: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio, reporting RF_KILL (radio enabled), Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM, RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.

Comment: Check these answers as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1119898/slow-speed-when-using-a-wifi-extender https://superuser.com/questions/435609/does-a-wireless-repeater-slow-things-down-for-everyone

Comment: Sadly those links are not useful for my case. I'm having a download speed of 200 kbps, while on another laptop, also with CentOS 7 connected to the same signal, I'm having 10 Mbps.